# Print text within javascript if-statement inside razor

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-table

I am trying to show an "X" if my if-statement is true. 
This is my code:

```
foreach (var opkod in Model.Select(x => x.AS_SC_OP).Distinct())
{
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => opkod)
        </td>
        <td></td>
        @foreach (var rad in Model)
        {
            if (rad.AS_SC_OP == opkod)
            {
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    for (j = 0; j < yearArray.length; j++)
                    {
                        if(@rad.AS_SC_AR == yearArray[j].indexOf() && @rad.AS_SC_VECKA == weekArray[j].indexOf() )
                        {
                            @Html.Raw("<td>");
                            @Html.Raw("<p>x</p>");
                            @Html.Raw("</td>");
                        }
                    }
                </script>
            }
        }
    </tr>
}
```

When i debug it seems to work, but nothing is printed on my page. Anyone got a clue what i have done wrong?

Comment: In the table header.

Comment: It's a integer.

Comment: The if-statement seems to work, and the lines that prints `<td>` and the `"x"` gets hit.

Comment: You are mixing two different things. Javascript will be evalualted on browser side and razor will be evaluated on server side. You can't do a decision based on a Javascript variable inside razor.

Comment: Oh okey. Is there anyway to create an array with razor?

Comment: You can do that normally as you do in C#. Just enclose that inside `@{ }` something like this `@{ var yearArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3} }`

Comment: Okey, i will try that. Thanks!

Comment: Can't find anny Add() method to use with the Array. Any ideas?

Comment: User `List<int>` You can't add to array. `@{ var yearArray = new List<int>(); }` You need to add using statement on top `@using System.Collections.Generic`

Comment: Can you show the target HTML snippet?